How do I add the qt mingw in Qt Creator?
I'm using Qt Creator for building my apps but my educational license has expired. I looked for alternative solutions and downloaded the Qt Creator community, but i can't find the Qt MinGW configure build.
I've looked for solutions to fix this but i still don't know how. I thought that downloading the source package offline will fix this but turns out it only contains source code. Appreciated for your help

The source package you downloaded provides the necessary files for you to build Qt Creator itself from your own machine. If I'm understanding what you mean by "Qt MinGW configure build", Qt Creator natively supports MinGW compilation and you can specify the compiler path when configuring a kit which you would then use to build projects (https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html).
